# How to pass mouse events from NSView to NSViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, nsviewcontroller, nsresponder

I have TabViewController, and i have Make custom NSView for it TabView which i have inherits in XIB.

Now i have successfully implemented all mouse handle events in TabView and worked.

I want the same events in TabViewController, But i can't.

I have tried with ways which are suggested on forums, blogs and apple docs.
But i could not get it.

```
TabViewController.xib 's custom view of TabView.
```

[image]

TabView with Mouse handle code.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;  
}

-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
}
```

Every mouse methods called. I want this in `TabViewController`.

If someone have did the same procedure please suggest me.

Comment: How does mouse events come into play with NSTabView?  Skipping details is not going to get you anything.

Comment: I m not using NSTabView. TabViewController is name of NSViewController. TabView is NSView which is custom view of TabViewController.